# React Native: Applying maxWidth to child of ScrollView not functioning as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

**Problem**

- I have a horizontal `ScrollView` in `react-native` that isn't working as expected when I have a `width` of the first child element that is greater than the `maxWidth` of the same child element (TouchableOpacity in the code below).
- The child element has the correct width, but it seems like the `ScrollView` is actually expanding to fill the full width of the screen when `maxWidth` is applied to the child element

```
  return (
    <ScrollView
      horizontal
      style={{
        flexGrow: 0, // To make the height of the horizontal ScrollView auto-adjust to its content
      }}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
      alwaysBounceHorizontal={false} // This prop is to disable the bounce effect on iOS when the content is smaller than the ScrollView
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          height: 48,
          borderRadius: 48 / 2,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          minWidth: 160,
          width: 600, // This is actually a variable that is calculated based on the screen width, but I simplified the example
          maxWidth: 250,
        }}
      >
        <Text>Place Holder Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      // Several other children with static 48 width and height are in here

    </ScrollView>
  )
```

**What I've tried**

- I can use `Math.min(MAX_WIDTH, widthDynamicallyCalculated)` and it functions as expected, but I want to figure out why the `ScrollView` is using what seems to be the `width` of the child as part of the calculation for how large the `ScrollView` should be

Any advice would be great!